# Automate copying resources from dependency project

Tags: ios, xcode, dependency-management, xcode-workspace

I have a static library which

1. Creates `.a` file
2. Exports public headers
3. Creates a `.bundle` containing resources

I have a workspace containing my project which depends on this lib. Library is also part of the workspace. I am able to work out the build dependencies on `.a` file and public headers. For the bundle, I have to manually add/update the bundle to my applications copy bundle resources build phase.

I want to automate this such that the bundle created in the `$(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)` gets  copied in the application bundle.

Is there a way to do this, may be a run script?

Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out.

I added a run script phase to my application. Script to copy the generated bundle to my application,

```
cp -R ${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/Mybundle.bundle ${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${PRODUCT_NAME}.app/Mybundle.bundle
```

Hope this helps!